# Morphology connected image to contour mask image, error?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, mathematical-morphology

Here is my [image: Morphology connected image] and I want to do mask and get this as[image: Output]

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# use morphology to close figure
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (35,35))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, )

# find contours and bounding boxes
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for count in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [count], 0, 255, -1)
```

So..Please tell how can I get this output?
how do I remove this black patch ?

Comment: What output do you have with your code?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer to your earlier post, get the contours and draw the filled contours on a black background. That is what I did and it works fine. Go back to my earlier answer and review it again. I create `mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)` to create a black background. Then I drew a white filled contour on it with `cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], 0, 255, -1)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314771/how-to-enclose-the-irregular-figure-contour-and-fill-it-with-with-5px-dots-in-op/64323622?noredirect=1#comment113759356_64323622 where it is answered already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enclose the irregular figure contour and fill it with with 5px dots in opencv using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314771/how-to-enclose-the-irregular-figure-contour-and-fill-it-with-with-5px-dots-in-op)